# Google Alerts for images

Tags: google-image-search, google-alerts

We use Google alerts quite a lot to keep in touch with what's being said about our company, but what we’ve found really useful lately is using the reverse image search tool in Google Images to search for our images appearing around the web. However, this is a manual and quite tedious process and we were wandering whether it was possible to do a "reverse image search Google Alert".

In other words, you could upload you images and then each time they were used on the web you would get an email alerting you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not currently possible to use Google Alerts for images. However, there are a few options that you may want to try (not all are automatic):

- [**Who Stole My Pictures**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/who-stole-my-pictures/) is a Firefox extension that allows you to target an image for a reverse search on a selection of search engines
- [**Image Raider**](http://www.imageraider.com/) is an automated reverse-image search tool – spend a few minutes adding your photo or image catalogue, and we’ll let you know when we find any other websites using them.
- [**TinEye**](http://tineye.com/) is a reverse image search engine. You can submit an image to TinEye to find out where it came from, how it is being used, if modified versions of the image exist, or to find higher resolution versions.

There are likely a number of others; [here's the google search I used](https://www.google.com/search?q=who%27s+using+my+photos&oq=who%27s+using+my+photos).

Answer (score -2):

Checkout [www.picmatch.ca](http://www.picmatch.ca)

They will search for your images periodically, and alert you when they are found.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the site, please disclose that in your answer.  Thanks!